# How can I use the new collasce features to make these 2 statments into 1 line?

Tags: c#

Using the new C# features for null checks, could I reduce these 2 lines into one and still ensure it is safe to do so? i.e. no null errors

```
 var carTypes = @Model.CarSubTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LookupId == item.SubType);
 var carTypeName = carTypes!= null ? carTypes.Name : "";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to write:

```
var carTypeName = @Model.CarSubTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LookupId == item.SubType)?.Name
                  ?? "";
```

The [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator check if the left operand is `null` : if it is not it evaluates `Name` else it stops the evalutation of the expression and the operator [`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) let you define the value used for the assignment.

Comment: note that this isn't strictly the same; if `carTypes` is non-null, and the `.Name` *is* null, then the original code would produce `null`, where-as your code would produce `""`. Which is probably *better*, but: it isn't the same

Comment: .Name won't be null but if it adds another level of safety I'll take it